# Backbone.js generic template for multiple similar object properties.

Tags: javascript, backbone.js

I have an object with has multiple similar complex properties. I would like to write a generic template that could be used for each property but am unsure how to proceed. My object looks similar to the below json representation. if the appointments / days were a collection, then I could iterate the collection binding a template normally. However, I need to model each 'day' as a property - for example, there will always be 5 entries.

However, I suppose the question is can you reuse the same template for each day. In effect, iterating each property using reflection?

```
{
  "days" : {
    "monday" : {
      "salesman" : "john",
      "customer" : "fred"
    },
    "friday" : {
      "salesman" : "paul",
      "customer" : "keith"
    },
    "tuesday" : {
      "salesman" : "dave",
      "customer" : "graham"
    },
    "wednesday" : {
      "salesman" : "james",
      "customer" : "keith"
    },
    "thursday" : {
      "salesman" : "keith",
      "customer" : "donald"
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you can change the format to something like this that would make it a lot easier because you can just use an iterator over days, and interpolate using known keys.

```
{ days: [{"weekday":"monday", "salesman":"john", "customer":"fred"}, ...]}
```

However, using the existing format you can solve this in  [Handlebars.js](http://handlebarsjs.com/) like this (should probably work in Mustache.js as well, but I haven't tried that):

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN"
        "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
    <title></title>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-1.7.1.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript"
            src="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/handlebars.js/1.0.0.beta2/handlebars.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<div id="output">
</div>
<script id="tmpl" type="x-template">
    <table>
    {{#key_value days}}
        <tr>
            <td><strong>{{key}}</strong></td>
            <td>{{value.salesman}}</td>
            <td>{{value.customer}}</td>
        </tr>
    {{/key_value}}
    </table>
</script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    var data = {
        "days":{
            "monday":{
                "salesman":"john",
                "customer":"fred"
            },
            "friday":{
                "salesman":"paul",
                "customer":"keith"
            },
            "tuesday":{
                "salesman":"dave",
                "customer":"graham"
            },
            "wednesday":{
                "salesman":"james",
                "customer":"keith"
            },
            "thursday":{
                "salesman":"keith",
                "customer":"donald"
            }
        }
    };

    Handlebars.registerHelper("key_value", function (obj, fn) {
        var soFar = "";
        var key;
        for (key in obj) {
            if (obj.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
                soFar += fn({key:key, value:obj[key]});
            }
        }
        return soFar;
    });

    var templateSrc = $("#tmpl").html();
    var template = Handlebars.compile(templateSrc);
    var result = template(data);

    $("#output").html(result);
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can do that.  You could make days a collection of day models.  An attribute of each day model could be an Appointments collection of Appointment models.  As you iterate through the collection of days you'll have the appointments collection for that day available.  In each day iterate through the appointments.

So in this case, you'd have a template for the day model and a template for the appointment model.  As you iterate through each collection you'd create a new Backbone.View and pass in the current model.

Comment: Agreed, I am going to move to a collection based model again. Thank you.